# Deployment in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

i am getting a problem 
i have deployed a war file, when i run localy through tomcat it works fine but when i run on another system by giveing my system ip and then project folder e.g

http:\192.168.0.145\DllTest it loads the applet but when i click on a button to load the functionality it is throwing an exception

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: http:\192.168.0.145:8080\DllTest\lib\jinvoke.dll

while it is working fine localy but not in another system. Please tell me what is the problem.

Is it a rights issue or something else.

Comment: Are you using any JNI interface?

Comment: no jni interface, but using a jinvoke.jar

Comment: @Tomas it is working fine locally. but there is no jinvoke.dll in lib folder rather there is jinvoke.jar in the lib folder, that is an isuue i guess

Comment: @user455964. The exception you are getting is tipically related with Dinamic Libraries when using JNI. Anyway, make sure you can acces the /DIITest/lib/ resources from your navigator. Maybe the server is configured to restrict access to this path from remote machines.

Comment: @Tomas it says.... HTTP Status 404 - /DllTest/lib/

Comment: Could you check PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH  on the machine it works. Most probably the directory which has the DLL is in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load a DLL on an external host. It has to be an absolute disk file system -as the exception message already hints. Your best bet is to download it manually, create a temp file and load it instead.

```
File dllFile = File.createTempFile("jinvoke", ".dll");
InputStream input = new URL(getCodeBase(), "lib/jinvoke.dll").openStream();
OuptutStream output = new FileOutputStream(dllFile);
// Write input to output and close streams the usual Java IO way.

// Then load it using absolute disk file system path.
System.loadLibrary(dllFile.getAbsolutePath());
dllFile.deleteOnExit();
```

Comment: Balus i am using an applet the inculding its jar in a jsp page i have made this in netbeans, i think there is another way around if i include the dll and then make a war file in netbeans

Comment: my point is that there is a dll with the jinvoke pacakge should i include that dll in the lib folder, basically in lib folder there is a jinvoke.jar when i extract that jar file it contains the folder "native" and then jinvoke.dll so my point is that it should extract it and find the jinvoke.dll

Comment: To be sure, do you have the DLL in `/lib` or `/WEB-INF/lib` folder? The `/WEB-INF` folder is inaccessible by public users. I'd suggest to put the DLL file in the same folder as the JAR file of the applet (and change the above code example to remove `lib/` part).

Comment: no there is no dll  in lib folder, let me check by putting a dll file in it

Comment: Oh? Where did you expect that the client would find the DLL file? You need to provide the DLL file along with the applet's JAR file.

Comment: and now it is giving an exception at my end tooo

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: http:\localhost:8080\DllTest\lib\jinvoke.dll

Comment: I've already answered that problem in my answer. Did you update the applet's code accordingly?

Comment: hi Balus, when i call dllFile.deleteOnExit(); method, it cannot delete the file the file still exists there.

Comment: It will only delete when the JVM exits, not when the applet exits :) If you want to delete it on exit of applet, then make it an applet property and delete it during `stop()`.

Comment: hmmmm thnx Balus :) i will try this out.

Comment: Balus i have made a method Stop(){ dllFile.deleteOnExit(); } but still not deleting and with dllFile.delete() not deleting the file

Comment: Oh it indeed won't work for dll files. Java has to unload it first. Right, better just do it when JVM exits.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark an answer accepted if it helped in solving the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: minus deleteFileOnExit(), the answer is accepted, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Balus any email if i want to contact you of any problem regarding java, java technologies, frameworks. i am new to this but have read java :).

Comment: Just press `Ask Question` button at right top of this page :) Enough people around who want to help -including me.

Comment: yeah i know that :D, but if more specificaly ask the question only from you i will visit your profile :)